# Can you move population to new cities with settlers?

Tags: civilization-5

Can I create a settler in city A, move him to city B and add him to city B's population?

You could do this in the old civ games.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**No, you can not move population with Settlers.**

Settlers and Workers in Civilization 5:

- Do not (directly) reduce population in the city they are built in.
- Can be built by cities of any size, notably without destroying the city.

In Civilization 4, (possibly earlier, but I don't remember) those limitations were replaced by workers/settlers using all excess food in the city while they were being constructed, effectively stopping growth.

In Civilization 5, settlers still use all excess food, stopping growth. Workers do not use food and can be built without any special limitations compared to other units.

To the best of my knowledge, if you did build a settler anyway, you can't add the settler to an existing city, but only start a new city.

Comment: Being able to move population in this way would be badly broken in Civ 5, considering how fast a small city can grow/build a settler and how that person's effectiveness would be multiplied in a large city.  A couple small cities and your large cities would gain a population point every turn.

Comment: @bwarner: I assume this imbalance is because each 'population point' is not equal. Going from 1->2 citizens represents a much smaller increase in total population than going from 10->11.

Comment: @Akusete That's how they try to explain it, but it doesn't really make sense, since total population is meaningless and every population point is equal in terms of the benefits it gives you.

Comment: @bwarner I disagree completely. More population in a big city lets you have a higher ratio of specialists, or people working on special tiles the Great People build. Those are things that small cities simply can't afford because they don't have enough tiles with 3+ food production. Those are greater options (you can still work the same normal tiles as small cities) and thus greater power. So, population matters more in a bigger city.

Comment: @WW: I think what he means is that there is no difference in how the game treats a 'population point'. Sure, having bigger cities lets you use them in better ways indirectly, but the population point is still treated the same regardless.

Comment: @WW Yep, what he said. =)  And I also find it hard to buy your argument that large cities can have a higher ratio of specialists.  A 3 population city with a single 4 food tile can support 2 specialists. I'd be interested in seeing a large city with twice as many specialists as people working tiles.

Comment: This is such a bummer.  I have a city next to 4 gold resources but it is in the mountains so growth is sloooooow.  I can only work two of the resources, and the next citizen is 100 turns away.

Comment: @fly Have you tried buying off some Maritime city-states?  That should significantly increase the rate at which your mountain city can grow.

Comment: @bwarner You're right the game treats each population point equally. My specific argument that larger cities can have a higher ratio of specialists is at least poorly worded, and possibly just wrong. I mean you probably have a lot more choice about what a population works in a larger city, generally just more options. That might not even be right either, it might be based on having awesome food tiles to work like your example, but that's still a reason why a given population point could be more useful in one city than in another.

Comment: It is not the case that Settlers "can be built by cities of any size". At least two Citizens are required.